# How to disable a MySQL query rollback in Magento after an unsuccessful payment operation?

Tags: mysql, magento, rollback

I've coded a manual script in [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento) to log my transactions in a payment process. The MySQL query works fine after a successful transaction and I can see the data in MySQL. But my query rollbacks (looks like inserted and deleted) after an unsuccesful payment. When I look into my MySQL table I can see the auto increment increases but no data.

My code is below. How can I block Magento to rollback my query?

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$results = $conn->query("insert into pos_transactions(order_id, transaction_time, ip, type) values('$orderId', '$sysDate', '$ip', 'Auth')");
```

Comment: Is your concern that you have gaps in the auto-increment sequence after this?  That seems like the desired behavior to me.

Comment: No I dont have problem with the gaps, my query works fine, but when I look in the data, I cant see any data. But after a successful payment operation I can see the data. magento rollbacks my data but leaves the auto-increment value. I can see the queries in mysql log in magento, but my situation is I dont want magento to delete my data after operation. Because this will be a log file.

Comment: where is this query being executed? in an observer? is it even being reached on a failure of a payment?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (tested in Magento Enterprise Edition 1.10):

$inSql = "INSERT INTO my_table(`fieldA`,`fieldB`) ";
    $inSql.= "VALUES('$valueA', '$valueB'); commit;";
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->query($inSql);

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

set table DB engine = MYISAM; 
because transaction commit and rollback feature is not supported by MYISAM.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM
( The major deficiency of MyISAM is the absence of transactions support. )

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
$conn = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

instead of

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

Magento will create a new connection to the database since you're not using the Singleton and this new connection won't have any open transaction.